# what does this java regular expression do?

Tags: javascript, java, regex

[~!#$^*!&()`\\(_+{}|:\"'<>?/,-=\.\[\]\n\t\r] 
can anyone please tell what does regular expression do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply matches for those symbols: ~!#$^*!&()`(_+{}|:"'<>?/,-=.[]\n\t\r

`\n` - New line symbol
`\t` - Tab symbol
`\r` - New line symbol

Check out [regex explainer](https://regexr.com/4vkqi).

Comment: BTW, I'm sure there is a typo in this regular expression, the author has forgotten a backslash in front of the minus sign. So instead of matching just a comma, minus sign, and equal sign,  `,-=` matches all characters between comma and equal sign.

Comment: FYI: `\n` matches a linefeed and `\r` a carriage return (nothing to do with “DOS mode”).